# Datepicker size in jQuery cannot be adjusted

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Im trying out the datepicker of JQuery and the previews given in the site

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

has different size than the actual one i placed on my code.
I tried changing the font-size of the datepicker table

```
.ui-datepicker table {width: 100%; font-size: .6em; border-collapse: collapse; margin:0 0 .4em; }
```

since I could not find a font size setting of the Header (Month Year), the topmost part in between the previous and next arrow.

The fonts in the calendar and the daynames already became smaller
but the Month year font size remained the same. Its really dissapointing. ;(

> .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month-year {font-size:.6em; width: 1%;}
>   .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month, 
>   .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year {  width: 1%;}`

Please help.

Thanks,
tinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a theme with the online ["Theme Roller"](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) rather than editing CSS manually. You can start from the existing theme that best matches your needs and tweak it to your liking. The benefits are:

1. You don't risk breaking CSS rules used for features or layout
2. The theme will be automatically reused by all other jQuery UI widgets

Additionally, the Theme Roller adds a link to the generated CSS (see the source code when you're done) so you can go back later and do further edits.

Comment: hi @Alvaro thanks for the rply, tried the Theme Roller and it worked :)